# Fill the table with the data took from migration table using the id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, database-migration

This is the front view of my home page.

[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDf50.jpg)

When I upload a .csv type file it will store in a migration table call "project" with 4 columns(id, name, created date, updated date). I want to fill the table on the home page by addressing {$project->id} given by the db table. How to do this without using maatwebsite package?

These are the 2 controllers.

**http/controllers/UploadFileController.php**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Models\Project;

 class UploadFileController extends Controller
 {
  public function index()
 {
  return view('/');
 }
  public function upload(Request $request)
 {
  $file = $request->file('csv');

  echo "<pre>";

  $project = new Project();

  $project->name = $request->name;

  $project->save();

  print_r($file);

  //Move Uploaded File
  $destinationPath = 'uploads';
  $file->move($destinationPath, $project->id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());

  return redirect("/project/{$project->id}");
  }
 }
```

**http/ProjectController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Project;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
  public function index($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    return view('home')->with('project', $project);
 }
}
```

Please can anyone help? Waiting for a quick reply.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @miken32 I edit it. hope it'll better now.